# How can I reference the line above a particular line in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
issue_stat     timestamp   state
    0          11:00:00     hi
    1          12:40:00     lo
    9          13:00:00     av
    3          15:00:00     hi 
    8          18:00:00     hi
    4          20:00:00     lo
```

I want to map the `state` of the line above `timestamp=18:00:00` to `jazz`. I MUST use the `timestamp=18:00:00` in my code. How would I do this?

I know how to map the `state` of `timestamp=18:00:00`:

```
dataframe.loc[dataframe['timestamp'] == '18:00:00', 'state'] = whatever
```

But I am having difficult pointing to the line above it. Again I emphasise, I MUST reference the `timestamp = 18:00:00` in my code.

So the output looks like this:

```
issue_stat     timestamp   state
     0          11:00:00     hi
     1          12:40:00     lo
     9          13:00:00     av
     3          15:00:00    jazz 
     8          18:00:00     hi
     4          20:00:00     lo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shift()` method moves the series in either direction. So to set the state of the cell where the following timestamp is 18:00:

```py
df.loc[df["timestamp"].shift(-1) == '18:00:00', 'state'] = 'jazz'
```

Produces:

```
   issue_stat           timestamp    state
0           0            11:00:00       hi
1           1            12:40:00       lo
2           9            13:00:00       av
3           3            15:00:00     jazz
4           8            18:00:00       hi
5           4            20:00:00       lo
```

Comment: Thanks @DobbyTheElf. Can I also ask, is there an easy way to map the `state` of the last row in the pandas dataframe? Say I wanted to change the `state` to jazz2.

Comment: `df.loc[df["timestamp"] == df.iloc[-1]["timestamp"], 'state'] = 'jazz'` works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift()`:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], \
    'B' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], \
    'state' : ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL']})
```

```
    A   B   state
0   1   A   NY
1   2   B   NY
2   3   C   NY
3   4   D   NY
4   5   E   NY
5   6   F   FL
6   7   G   FL
7   8   H   FL
8   9   I   FL
9   10  J   FL
```

I reference value `C` but value gets changed for value `B` - 1 line above that.

```
test_df.loc[test_df.index[test_df['B'] == 'C'] - 1, 'state'] = 'new'
test_df
```

```
    A   B   state
0   1   A   NY
1   2   B   new
2   3   C   NY
3   4   D   NY
4   5   E   NY
5   6   F   FL
6   7   G   FL
7   8   H   FL
8   9   I   FL
9   10  J   FL
```

But in your case you would chose the column `timestamp` instead of `B` and a value of your choosing.